# gradle copy: how to replace pattern with dynamic values?

Tags: gradle, copy

gradle copy: replace pattern with dynamic values. e.g.,

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
    from ("/path") {
        include "*.txt"

        eachFile { fcd ->
            File file = fcd.file
            File destFile = new File("/tmp", fcd.path)              
            destFile.text = file.text.replace("@FILE_NAME@", file.name)
        }
    }

    into "/tmp"
}
```

The changed target files are overridden by the copy, so they are not changed.